# single quotes being replaced quotes with #34

Tags: c#, string

I have the following code.

When this code is sent to the browser the single quotes are being replaced with & #39;

ASCX

```
<a runat="server" id="lnkPlay" href="#" >Play</a>
```

Code behind

```
  string onClickText = 
         "javascript:changeSrc('http://www.url.com/m/25_03_2012-Paul_R.mp3','Paul Robbins','25/03/2012');";

  lnkPlay.Attributes.Add("onClick", onClickText);
```

becomes this in the html

```
   <a href="UserControls/#" id="BodyContent_MainContent_CtrlMesssageSummary_lnkPlay" rel="test" onClick="javascript:changeSrc(&#39;http://www.url.com/m/25_03_2012-Paul_R.mp3&#39;,&#39;Paul Robbins&#39;,&#39;25/03/2012&#39;);">

                Play</a>
```

How do i stop this ??

Comment: How are you "sending the string to the browser"?

Comment: *How* are you sending it to the client/deducing that it has been HTML escaped? - what is that stray `";` for?

Comment: How are you sending this code to the browser?

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using to output that line to the browser.

Comment: updated code, oops i forgot to say what it was doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the single quotes using escape character as below :

```
javascript:changeSrc(\'http://www.url.co.uk/\',\'Text\',\'25/03/2012\');
```

as per [this article](http://qualitypoint.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/handling-single-quotes-in-php-and.html), if the above doesnt work try to esacpe/replace `"&#39;"`